# Invalid type for key imagem1, expected file, but got string

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uiimagejpegrepresentation

I tried to use `UIImagePNGRepresentation` but when i upload the images to Parse they are too big, but the small images were working fine. For that reason i tried to use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`, but it doesnt matter if the image is big or small, always get an error "Invalid type for key imagem1, expected file, but got string":

```
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(restaurante.imagem[0],0.75)
    let imageFile = PFFile(name:"image.png", data:imageData).description
    Restaurantes["imagem1"] = imageFile

    Restaurantes.saveInBackground()
```

Got a string? How? 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added `.description` to the end of the definition, so you're creating your `PFFile` instance and then getting the description of it. Remove that part of the line.

Comment: Dont know why the .description was there... But thank you!